# boost::asio fails to read more than 65536 bytes from file

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, boost-asio

I'm failing to read more than `65536` bytes into a buffer from a file using `boost::asio::windows::stream_handle` asynchronously.

Starting from `65537`th byte the buffer contains the the data from the very beginning of the file, rather than the expected data.

Here is a code example, which reproduces the issue:

```
auto handle = ::CreateFile(L"BigFile.xml", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, nullptr);
boost::asio::io_service ios;

boost::asio::windows::stream_handle streamHandle(ios, handle);

const auto to_read_bytes = 100000;
char buffer[to_read_bytes];

boost::asio::async_read(streamHandle, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, to_read_bytes), [](auto &ec, auto read) {
    std::cout << "Bytes read: " << read << std::endl;
});

ios.run();

auto bufferBegin = std::string(buffer, 38);
auto bufferCorrupted = std::string(buffer + 65536, 38);   // <- it contains bytes from the beginning of the file

std::cout << "offset 0: " << bufferBegin << std::endl;
std::cout << "offset 65536: " << bufferCorrupted << std::endl;   

::CloseHandle(handle);
```

That code produces an output:

```
> Bytes read: 100000  
> offset 0: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
> offset 65536: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The source file is bigger than 65536.

This is reproducible with boost 1.61 + VS2015. Also that issue was in boost 1.55 + VS2010.
Operating systems are: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.

My questions are:
1. Is that the known limitation in `boost::asio` or in `WinAPI`?
2. If it is the known limitation, what would be the safe size of the buffer to read data? Is it safe to have a buffer of size 65536, or it should be smaller?

Comment: This is not a limit in the windows API -- the limit that is present there (in older API methods) is 2^32 not 2^16.

Comment: You may want to specify what versions of software you are using (boost, windows, and visual C++)

Comment: @nate Yeah, definitely I need to specify the versions. Thanks for reminding. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The problem might be with stack limit which is usually 100,000. Use `std::string` which allocates memory on heap, instead of using `char buffer[100000];` which allocates on stack. Or just use `to_read_bytes = 4096` it doesn't get faster if you increase that buffer size.

Comment: @ BarmakShemirani Nope, it is not stack limit. The same behavior is when the buffer is allocated in the heap.

Comment: Have you checked your source file (e.g. in Notepad) to make sure it really doesn't have that data repeating at the 64kb mark?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yeah, I've checked this. The source file is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is neither a limitation of Asio, Windows, nor buffer sizes.  Rather, Asio is performing exactly what it has been told to do within its specifications: it is reading `100000` bytes from a regular file *as-if* it was a *stream*.  With [`windows::stream_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__stream_handle.html):

- [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) will be composed of zero or more intermediate `async_read_some()` operations until either the number of bytes requested by the application has been transferred, or until an error occurs

  > This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `async_read_some` function, and is known as a *composed operation*.
- [`async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__basic_stream_handle/async_read_some.html) operations may read less than the number of requested bytes

  > The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes.
- each intermediate `async_read_some()` operation will read from the start of the stream

As the file handle being used is not truly a stream, but rather a regular file, consider using the [`windows::random_access_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__random_access_handle.html) and [`async_read_at(device, 0, ...)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_at/overload1.html).  The [Random-Access HANDLEs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/random_access_handle.html) documentation notes:

> Boost.Asio provides Windows-specific classes that permit asynchronous read and write operations to be performed on HANDLEs that refer to regular files.

When using `windows::random_access_handle` and `async_read_at()`:

- `async_read_at()` will be composed of zero or more intermediate `async_read_some_at()` operations until either the number of bytes requested by the application has been transferred, or until an error occurs
- [`async_read_some_at()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__basic_random_access_handle/async_read_some_at.html) operations may read less than the number of requested bytes
- each intermediate `async_read_some_at()` operation will use an offset corresponding to end of the previous read when reading from the device (e.g. the initial offset + current bytes transferred)

Comment: Thanks, for answer. Now it's clear how to read big file asynchronously. But I still think it's a bug in Asio. At least a bug in the documentation, where this behavior should be mentioned. As a simple operation gives wrong result without any compile-time or run-time notification.

Comment: @Alexander I believe the behavior is documented.  I doubt any compile-time errors are possible.  However, by querying for file information by `HANDLE`, it may be possible for `stream_handle::assign()` to fail with a not-supported error, assuming there is no compelling use case to support `stream_handle` for regular files.

Comment: I cannot find any warnings in the documentation about the limitation that async reading more than 2^16 bytes won't work. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/asio/windows/basic_stream_handle.hpp - here documented method `async_read_some()` , which says nothing about it. And here mentioned usage `async_read()` when we need to get guaranteed amount of data read.

Comment: @Alexander There is no limitation.  The `async_read()` composed operations can asynchronously read more than 65536 bytes.  The example in the question even indicates that it successfully read 10000: the first `async_read_some()` reads 65536 bytes (bytes 0 to 65536 in the file), and the second `async_read_some()` reads 34464 bytes (bytes 0 to 34464 in the file).  I understand that this is not the desired behavior for your use case, but it is for a stream.  The documentation explicitly states `windows::random_access_handle` should be used for regular files.

Answer (score 6):

As [Tanner Sansbury says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857842/4885801), you opened a file with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` but you're trying to use it as a stream. It is not.

`async_read()` is basically this loop in [`asio/impl/read.hpp`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/impl/read.hpp#L255):

```
for (;;)
{
    stream_.async_read_some(buffers_, ASIO_MOVE_CAST(read_op)(*this));

    buffers_.consume(bytes_transferred);
    total_transferred_ += bytes_transferred;

    if (!ec && bytes_transferred == 0)
        break;
}
```

The actual maximum number of bytes that will be read in one call comes from [`completion_condition.hpp`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/completion_condition.hpp#L28):

```
enum default_max_transfer_size_t { default_max_transfer_size = 65536 };
```

The problem is the `async_read_some()` call above. You'll notice that there's no offset to tell it where to start reading. Because you are using asynchronous reads (also called "overlapped" on Windows), an offset has to be specified for every read.

This is where it ends up, in [`asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_handle_service.ipp`](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_handle_service.ipp#L476):

```
DWORD bytes_transferred = 0;
op->Offset = offset & 0xFFFFFFFF;
op->OffsetHigh = (offset >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
BOOL ok = ::ReadFile(impl.handle_, buffer.data(),
    static_cast<DWORD>(buffer.size()),
    &bytes_transferred, op);
```

`op->Offset` and `op->OffsetHigh` are always 0. The pointer inside your buffer will advance correctly, but every chunk will be read from the start of the file.

There's an `async_read_some_at()` that's available, which you should use instead, as well as `windows::random_access_handle`. This will set the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members correctly. You will have to keep track of the number of bytes read yourself.

The documentation for the [OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) structure says this:

> The Offset and OffsetHigh members together represent a 64-bit file position. It is a byte offset from the start of the file or file-like device, and it is specified by the user; the system will not modify these values. The calling process must set this member before passing the OVERLAPPED structure to functions that use an offset, such as the ReadFile or WriteFile (and related) functions.

There's also this part in [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The system does not maintain the file pointer on asynchronous handles to files and devices that support file pointers (that is, seeking devices), therefore the file position must be passed to the read and write functions in the related offset data members of the OVERLAPPED structure. For more information, see WriteFile and ReadFile.

Comment: Your answer definitely deserves more that one upvote. I submitted the bug report here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12383 . And I'll add a link to your answer to the bug report later. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk The main repo is on github, it's just boostified when released. You may have a quicker answer if you file the bug report [on the github tracker](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues). Not sure though.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk Well, I got the *how*, but he got the *why*: your file isn't a stream. You should accept his answer, I'll modify my post so it doesn't suggest it's a bug anymore.

Comment: ok, I'll accept another answer, as he provides the working solution to fix. But your answer is also very valuable as it explains the root cause in details.